# Unable to get data from List Generated into webpage ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc

When trying to get data from a list *(created by an excel spreadsheet)* in my HomeController, I run into an issue where the data is generated, but I'm unable to produce it onto a webpage. If I try to generate it using the model from the page directly, I get `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` With out it even loading to the initial page.

My HomeController (Removed some items from the list for demonstration of issue):

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<List<DataForProactiveContact>> Import(IFormFile file)
        {
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            var list = new List<DataForProactiveContact>();
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
                    var rowcount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
                    for (int row = 2; row < rowcount; row++)
                    {
                        list.Add(new DataForProactiveContact
                        {
                            regionID = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                            storeID = worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                            productStatus = worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

My Model:

```
    public class DataForProactiveContact
    {
        public string regionID { get; set; }
        public string storeID { get; set; }
        public string productStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

And my HTML:

```
@model IEnumerable<DataForProactiveContact>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<h2>Test Run</h2>
<body>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="6000">
        <div class="container">
            <form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Import" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" name="file" />
                <button type="submit">Import Excel Form</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Region</th>
                <th>Store</th>
                <th>Product Status</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var p in ViewBag.DataForProactiveContact)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@p.regionID</td>
                    <td>@p.storeID</td>
                    <td>@p.productStatus</td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
</body>
```

If I run the webpage with out the @foreach statement, I get the data generated and sent to a source data page called Import where my data is shown, rather than in a webpage.

My Goal is to get the information I have from the Model/List variable, put into the webpage and displayed as a table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Dependencies are EPPlus NonCommercial.
Running Firefox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Jazb Unfortunately not, I understand the reason why the item returns a Null. I'm just not understanding how to get data from one page to another.

Comment: Does you HTML represents index view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an index view, but don' t have any data. Model should be added

```
public IActionResult Index()
 {
    List <DataForProactiveContact> model = ...your code to fill list
     return View(model);
}
```

and fix the view

```
@if( Model != null)
{
@foreach (var p in Model.DataForProactiveContact)
 {
                <tr>
                    <td>@p.regionID</td>
                    <td>@p.storeID</td>
                    <td>@p.productStatus</td>
                </tr>
 }
}
```